# How to get username of currenlty logged on user authservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I would like to get the currently loged in username so i can display it. But i dont know how to do it  ? Any ideas ? I am using authservice Here is my angular controller in which i would like to get the username.

```
myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');
$scope.meetups = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });


  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }
}]);
```

my main angular controller code
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/api/meetups', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/prive', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/prive.html',
      controller: 'userController',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/logout', {
      controller: 'logoutController',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
      controller: 'registerController',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/one', {
      template: '<h1>This is page one!</h1>',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/two', {
      template: '<h1>This is page two!</h1>',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) {
      AuthService.getUserStatus()
      .then(function(){
        if (next.access.restricted && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
          $location.path('/login');
          $route.reload();
        }
      });
  });
});







myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');
$scope.meetups = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });


  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }





}]);
```

my second angular code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.login = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call login from service
      AuthService.login($scope.loginForm.username, $scope.loginForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username and/or password";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        });

    };

  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

  $scope.post = function(){
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };
}]);

app.controller('logoutController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.logout = function () {

      // call logout from service
      AuthService.logout()
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
        });

    };

    $scope.gotoregister = function () {




          $location.path('/register');


    };
    $scope.gotoprive = function () {




          $location.path('/prive');


    };

}]);

app.controller('registerController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.register = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call register from service
      AuthService.register($scope.registerForm.username, $scope.registerForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        });

    };

}]);
```

and my services

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService',
  ['$q', '$timeout', '$http',
  function ($q, $timeout, $http) {

    // create user variable
    var user = null;

    // return available functions for use in the controllers
    return ({
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
      getUserStatus: getUserStatus,
      login: login,
      logout: logout,
      register: register
    });

    function isLoggedIn() {
      if(user) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    function getUserStatus() {
      return $http.get('/user/status')
      // handle success
      .success(function (data) {
        if(data.status){
          user = true;
        } else {
          user = false;
        }
      })
      // handle error
      .error(function (data) {
        user = false;
      });
    }

    function login(username, password) {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a post request to the server
      $http.post('/user/login',
        {username: username, password: password})
        // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
          if(status === 200 && data.status){
            user = true;
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            user = false;
            deferred.reject();
          }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function logout() {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a get request to the server
      $http.get('/user/logout')
        // handle success
        .success(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.resolve();
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function register(username, password) {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a post request to the server
      $http.post('/user/register',
        {username: username, password: password})
        // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
          if(status === 200 && data.status){
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            deferred.reject();
          }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

}]);
```

Comment: please show the code of authservice. also you can set user details in cookies so that whenever user refresh the page it will not be lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should probably work, maybe you will need to make some small adjustments because i don't know how exactly is your app structured, but this will work.

First you need to change your AuthService to look like this

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AuthService',
  ['$q', '$timeout', '$http',
  function ($q, $timeout, $http, $cookies) {

    // create user variable
    var user = null;

    // we must create authMemberDefer var so we can get promise anywhere in app
    var authenticatedMemberDefer = $q.defer();

    // return available functions for use in the controllers
    return ({
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
      getUserStatus: getUserStatus,
      login: login,
      logout: logout,
      register: register,
      getAuthMember: getAuthMember,
      setAuthMember: setAuthMember
    });

    function isLoggedIn() {
      if(user) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    //this is function that we will call each time when we need auth member data
    function getAuthMember() {
        return authenticatedMemberDefer.promise;
    }
    //this is setter function to set member from coockie that we create on login
    function setAuthMember(member) {
        authenticatedMemberDefer.resolve(member);
    }

    function getUserStatus() {
      return $http.get('/user/status')
      // handle success
      .success(function (data) {
        if(data.status){
          user = true;
        } else {
          user = false;
        }
      })
      // handle error
      .error(function (data) {
        user = false;
      });
    }

    function login(username, password) {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a post request to the server
      $http.post('/user/login',
        {username: username, password: password})
        // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
          if(status === 200 && data.status){
            user = true;
            deferred.resolve();

            //**
            $cookies.putObject('loginSession', data);
            // here create coockie for your logged user that you get from this response, im not sure if its just "data" or data.somethingElse, check you response you should have user object there


          } else {
            user = false;
            deferred.reject();
          }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function logout() {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a get request to the server
      $http.get('/user/logout')
        // handle success
        .success(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.resolve();
          //on log out remove coockie
          $cookies.remove('loginSession');

        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          user = false;
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

    function register(username, password) {

      // create a new instance of deferred
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // send a post request to the server
      $http.post('/user/register',
        {username: username, password: password})
        // handle success
        .success(function (data, status) {
          if(status === 200 && data.status){
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            deferred.reject();
          }
        })
        // handle error
        .error(function (data) {
          deferred.reject();
        });

      // return promise object
      return deferred.promise;

    }

}]);
```

after that changes in authService, you must make this on your app run, so each time application run (refresh) it first check coockie to see if there is active session(member) and if there is it will set it inside our AuthService.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService, $cookies) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
        function(event, next, current) {
            if ($cookies.get('loginSession')) {
                var session = JSON.parse($cookies.get('loginSession'));
                AuthService.setAuthMember(session);
            } else {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
});
```

And simply anywhere where you want to get auth member you have to do this, first include in your controller/directive AuthService and do this

```
AuthService.getAuthMember().then(function(member){
 console.log(member);
 //here your member should be and you can apply any logic or use that data where     u want
});
```

I hope this helps you, if you find any difficulties i'm happy to help

Comment: First of all let me thank you u r awsome for taking your time and help me i will work on it and get back to u

Comment: No problem, i'm happy to help, let me know if it works when u test it.

Comment: I get AuthService.getAuthMember is not a function

Comment: Check if you included authService properly in controller/directive, and check if your return is same like this in AuthService

Comment: Can you please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806480/how-to-get-loggedin-user-info-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods how you can get currently logged user, it mostly depends on you app structure and API, you probably should have API end point to get authenticated member and that call is made on each app refresh.
Also if you can show us your authservice.

Edit:

Also on successful login you can store information about logged user in coockie like this

```
   function doLogin(admin) {
     return authMemberResources.login(details).then(function(response) {
       if (response) {
         $cookies.putObject('loginSession', response);
       } else {
         console.log('wrong details');
       }
     });
```

So basically you can use angularjs coockies service and make loginSession coockie like that, and on app refresh or anywhere where you need logged user info, you can get that like this:

```
            if ($cookies.get('loginSession')) {
                var session = JSON.parse($cookies.get('loginSession'));
                console.log(session);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just a demo example

> in login controller

```
var login = function(credentials) {
    AuthService.login(credentials).then(function(result) {
        var user = result.data;
        AuthService.setCurrentUser(user);
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        if (err.status < 0) {
            comsole.error('Please check your internet connection!');
        } else {
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
        }
    });
};
```

> in AuthService

```
.factory('AuthService', function($http, $cookies, BASE_URL) {
    var service = {
        login: function(formdata) {
            return $http.post(BASE_URL + '/login', formdata);
        },
        setCurrentUser: function(user) {
            $cookies.putObject('currentUser', user);
        },
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            return angular.isDefined($cookies.getObject('currentUser'));
        },
        getFullName: function() {
            return $cookies.getObject('currentUser').firstName + ' ' + $cookies.getObject('currentUser').lastName;
        }
    }
    return service;
});
```

> in the controller which attached with your dashboard view

```
$scope.$watch(AuthService.isAuthenticated, function(value) {
    vm.isAuthenticated = value;
    if (vm.isAuthenticated) {
        vm.fullName = AuthService.getFullName();
        vm.currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.factory('AuthService', function($http, $cookies, BASE_URL) {
    var service = {
        login: function(formdata) {
            return $http.post(BASE_URL + '/login', formdata);
        },
        setCurrentUser: function(user) {
            $cookies.putObject('currentUser', user);
        },
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            return angular.isDefined($cookies.getObject('currentUser'));
        },
        getFullName: function() {
            return $cookies.getObject('currentUser').firstName + ' ' + $cookies.getObject('currentUser').lastName;
        },
       getAuthenticatedMember: function() {
            if ($cookies.get('currentUser')) {
            return JSON.parse($cookies.get('currentUser'));
        }
       }
    }
    return service;
});
```

That should work, i added new function getAuthenticatedMember and you can use it where you need it. And you can use it like this:

```
$scope.$watch(AuthService.isAuthenticated, function(value) {
  vm.isAuthenticated = value;
  if (vm.isAuthenticated) {
    vm.currentUser = AuthService.getAuthenticatedMember();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much but where do i add the code u gave mein my angular controller ?

Comment: And how do i use it please help me

Comment: `$scope.$watch(AuthService.isAuthenticated, function(value) {
    vm.isAuthenticated = value;
    if (vm.isAuthenticated) {
        var currentUser = AuthService.getAuthenticatedMember();
    }
});`

Comment: Can you paste your auth service so i can see how it looks ?

Comment: I dont hae a function authservice all i have is functions with dependencie on authservice

Comment: I already asked, but can you please show me your authservice ?

Comment: Well... You need to create auth service then, and how you register your users and log in to page if you dont have one...

Comment: I uppdated my questiion please help

Comment: Give me moment to write everything in your auth service